# Views taxonomy exposed filter, show tree/hierarchy in drop down menu

Tags: views, 6, taxonomy-terms, input-formats

I have an exposed taxonomy filter that allows the user the filter by term. The vocabulary is 2 tiers, however in the exposed filter menu the hierarchy appears flat.

Is there a method/module to show the hierarchy with indentation or prefixing child terms with "-", similar to the taxonomy term selection menu from the node edit form itself.

x-post from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222875/drupal-views-taxonomy-exposed-filter-show-tree-hierarchy-in-drop-down-menu

SOLUTION:

The filter Taxonomy: Term ID (with Depth) will display the option "Show Hierarchy In Dropdown" when you select the Dropdown widget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filter Taxonomy: Term ID (with Depth) will display the option "Show Hierarchy In Dropdown" when you select the Dropdown widget.